# Click CSS Element with Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button using Selenium.

Below is the code

```
<button class="_11f5fc88e3dec7bfec55f7f49d581d78-scss _238c8d0c29802f43d5fb66614d042cfa-scss" title="Play" aria-label="Play" data-testid="play-button" style xpath="1">
```

I tried to do this by the css selector:

```
searchButton = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="_11f5fc88e3dec7bfec55f7f49d581d78-scss _238c8d0c29802f43d5fb66614d042cfa-scss"]').click()
```

MY ERROR: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Am I approaching this wrong? Im not understanding the error.

Comment: That is not a valid CSS selector. To get the CSS selector, right-click on the mouse on the element(<button class) and click copy > copy selector

Comment: @CarMan does the below answer has solved your issue? if yes, feel free to accept the correct answer with click `√` icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link of how to use different selectors..
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

It is recommended to Copy css selector path by inspecting particular element on website then mouse right click -> copy -> copy css path

or by analyzing the code manually enter path

Here p is paragraph tag and class name is content

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.content')

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

This error appear because you use `.find_elements`, it will return a list.

To solve this issue, try this approach:

1. Using `.find_element`, without `s`.
2. Or still using `.find_elements` but with index, like this:

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class="_11f5fc88e3dec7bfec55f7f49d581d78-scss _238c8d0c29802f43d5fb66614d042cfa-scss"]')[0].click()
```